# when can you extend a map from a Hilbert basis?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $H$ and $K$ are Hilbert spaces and $H$ has Hilbert basis $h_i$.  What is a necessary and sufficient condition for elements $k_i$ of K so that $h_i \mapsto k_i$ extends to a continuous linear map $H \rightarrow K$?

Comment: Is the index of the basis of $K$ the same as for $H$?

Comment: I don't mean for the $k_i$ to be a basis but just elements of $K$ to which the $h_i$ have been mapped (according to their index: $h_i \mapsto k_i$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition is that $$\|\sum_j\alpha_jk_j\|\leq c\,\|\alpha\|_2$$
for a fixed positive constant $c$ and all $\alpha\in\ell^2$. But this of course doesn't tell you much; I don't think a useful condition can be established.  After all, what you want is to characterize all the images of all orthonormal bases under all bounded operators. Sounds like too ambitious.